# can a running blockchain fork from PoW to PoA?

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, pow

can a running public blockchain hard fork from PoW to PoA?

Comment: Well, the Ethereum mainnet is doing just that - it just takes a few years to accomplish due to development requirements. But unsure how the process could be done for other networks when the process is polished.